# Prefill magento form after submitting a form with captcha

Tags: magento, session

I have created a custom form extension in magento. After submitting a form, if captcha is incorrect, how to prefill the form values. The form will not save in backend. Here is my controller file,

class namespace_moduleName_IndexController extends

Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER     ='contacts/email/sender_email_identity';

```
 public function indexAction() {


    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function postAction() {

      $formId = 'form_id';         
    $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);

    if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
        if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString($this->getRequest(), $formId))) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('form_id')->__('The CAPTCHA you entered is not correct. Go back and try it again'));
            $this->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
           // Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            $this->_redirectReferer();
            return;
        }
    } 

     $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
       if ($post) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
                try {
                    $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                    $postObject->setData($post);

                    $error = false;
                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                        $error = true;
                    }
                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                        $error = true;
                   }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['message']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                       $error = true;
                  }

                if ($error) {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                        $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                        /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                        $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                                    ->sendTransactional(
                                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                                        null,
                                        array('data' => $postObject)
                        );

                        if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                            throw new Exception();
                        }
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('form_id')->__('Your enquiry for the product was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us. '));
                        $this->_redirectReferer();    

                } catch (Exception $e) {

                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('form_id')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                    $this->_redirectReferer();
                }

            } 
            else {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('form_id')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
               $this->_redirectReferer();
            }
        }

   protected function _getCaptchaString($request, $formId) {
       $captchaParams = $request->getPost(Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE);
       return $captchaParams[$formId];
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Before Captcha check and redirection. you can save the submitted data in Registry. and you can access saved Registry data on Form Detail Page.

When you send the email, you can delete Registry Data.

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
```

**Register variable**

```
Mage::register('name', $post['name']);
Mage::register('email', $post['email']);
Mage::register('message', $post['message']);
```

**Fetch registry variable value in template using below method**

```
Mage::registry('name');
Mage::registry('email');
Mage::registry('message');
```

**Destroy / Unregister the variable**

```
Mage::unregister('name');
Mage::unregister('email');
Mage::unregister('message');
```

Comment: Where to call the register variable in magento controller action. I have called in postAction() method. But its not working.

Comment: You can below this line $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);